# grep "^ *`word" syntax linux

Tags: linux, csh

I'm using linux at work and I'm a newbie by all means and I was told to use a grep command

```
grep –r <missing err> . | grep "^ *`define"
```

I'm assuming the ^ stands for the start of a line? but I'm not sure what the * and the ` (tick) are for?

Can someone please explain how this works please!  I would be very grateful!

Comment: Read [grep(1)](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_grep.htm) man page (or type `man grep`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming the `^` stands for the start of a line?

Yes

> ...but I'm not sure what the `*` and the ` (tick) are for?

The star says *match the preceding character 0 or more times*.

The backtick can perform command substitution (like `$()`). It still seems to do that even when quoted. However, it doesn't make sense to use just one like that (they need to be balanced). If you want a literal backtick, precede it with `\`.

For more information, run `man grep` (it has the definitions for those symbols).